# How to resolve this differential equation with Laplace transform?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

$$\mathcal{L}\left\{ f'(t)\right\} =s\mathcal{L}\left\{ f(t)\right\} -f(0)$$

---

$$\begin{cases} x' +x - y' = -t \\ x' + y' + y = 1 \end{cases}$$,

$$X=\mathcal{L}\left\{ x\right\}, \ Y=\mathcal{L}\left\{ y\right\}$$

---

$$\begin{cases} sX-x(0) +X -sY+y(0) =  \int_{0}^{+\infty}-te^{-st}\,dt  \\ sX-x(0)+ sY-y(0)+ Y =  \int_{0}^{+\infty}1\cdot e^{-st}\,dt  \end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases} sX-x(0) +X -sY+y(0) =-\frac{1}{s^2} \\ sX-x(0)+ sY-y(0)+ Y = \frac 1 s \end{cases}$$

---

$$\begin{cases} (s+1)X -sY =-\frac{1}{s^2}+x(0)-y(0) \\ sX+(s+1)Y= \frac 1 s+x(0)+y(0) \end{cases}$$

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}s+1 &-s\\s&s+1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}X\\Y\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}-\frac{1}{s^2}+x(0)-y(0)\\\frac 1 s+x(0)+y(0) \end{array}\right)$$

---

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}s+1 &-s\\s&s+1\end{array}\right)^{-1}
=
\frac{1}{(s+1)^2+s^2}\left(\begin{array}{cc} s+1&s\\-s&s+1\end{array}\right)$$

---

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}X\\Y\end{array}\right)=\frac{1}{(s+1)^2+s^2}\left(\begin{array}{cc}-\frac{s+1}{s^2}+(s+1)(x(0)-y(0))+1+s(x(0)+y(0))\\\frac 1 s-s(x(0)-y(0))+\frac{s+1}{s}+(s+1)(x(0)+y(0)) \end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Now apply that $\frac1{(s+1)^2+s^2}=\frac{2}{(2s+1)^2+1}=\frac12\frac1{(s+0.5)^2+0.25}$ and do the reverse look-up of the transformation table.

Comment: so:$$ \frac1{(s+1)^2+s^2}=\frac{2}{(2s+1)^2+1}=\frac12\frac1{(s+0.5)^2+0.25} = \frac{4}{2} \frac{0.25}{(s+0.5)^{2}+0.25} = 2 e^{t}\sin{\frac{t}{4}} $$ but what I what should I do with
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}-\frac{s+1}{s^2}+(s+1)(x(0)-y(0))+1+s(x(0)+y(0))\\\frac 1 s-s(x(0)-y(0))+\frac{s+1}{s}+(s+1)(x(0)+y(0)) \end{array}\right)$$ ?

Comment: Yes, for some of the terms. But observe that it is just the factor to the vector that contains other $s$-dependent terms.

Comment: So, this solutions $$2 e^{t}\sin{\frac{t}{4}} \left(\begin{array}{cc}-\frac{s+1}{s^2}+(s+1)(x(0)-y(0))+1+s(x(0)+y(0))\\\frac 1 s-s(x(0)-y(0))+\frac{s+1}{s}+(s+1)(x(0)+y(0)) \end{array}\right)$$ is final?

Comment: No, you need to first combine the factor with the entries, then apply the inverse transform. In the final result there should be no $s$.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean. :/

Comment: You have a Laplace transformed function/equation, where $s$ is the independent variable. You have the un-/back-transformed function/equation where $t$ is the independent variable. At no point is there a formula with a mix of $s$ and $t$ dependent terms.

Comment: $$\frac1{(s+1)^2+s^2}=\frac{2}{(2s+1)^2+1}=\frac12\frac1{(s+0.5)^2+0.25} = {\cal L}^{-1}\left[ \frac{4}{2} \frac{0.25}{(s+0.5)^{2}+0.25}\right] = 2 e^{\frac{t}{2}}\sin{\frac{t}{4}}$$

Comment: but how to get rid of $s$ from this $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}-\frac{s+1}{s^2}+(s+1)(x(0)-y(0))+1+s(x(0)+y(0))\\\frac 1 s-s(x(0)-y(0))+\frac{s+1}{s}+(s+1)(x(0)+y(0)) \end{array}\right)$$ ?

Comment: You don't. You have to go one or two steps back where there are no partial inverse transformations.

Comment: So i must calculate ${\cal L}^{-1}$ from $ \left(\begin{array}{cc}-\frac{s+1}{s^2}+(s+1)(x(0)-y(0))+1+s(x(0)+y(0))\\\frac 1 s-s(x(0)-y(0))+\frac{s+1}{s}+(s+1)(x(0)+y(0)) \end{array}\right)$ ? but I don't know how.

Comment: Note also that with $a=b=\frac12$ you get $${\cal L}^{-1}\left[\frac{b}{(s+a)^2+b^2}\right]=e^{-at}\sin(bt)=e^{-t/2}\sin(t/2).$$

Comment: No, you need to divide this vector by the determinant. The method is partial fraction decomposition for all the fractional expressions until only expressions remain that you can find in the transformation table.

Comment: It's to difficult. I don't know, can you show me or it's to long to write in TeX?

Answer (score 0):

To compare against another solution method: Consider $z=x+iy$, then, using undetermined coefficients,
\begin{align}
(1+i)z'+z=i-t&\implies z = Ae^{-(1-i)t/2}+Bt+C,\\~\\
(1+i)B+Bt+C=i-t&\implies B=-1, C=1+2i\\~\\
z(0)=A+C&\implies A=z(0)-1-2i
\end{align}

All together
$$
z(t)=(z(0)-1-2i)e^{-(1-i)t/2}-t+1+2i,
$$
so that in real components
$$
x(t)=e^{-t/2}[(x(0)-1)\cos(t/2)-(y(0)-2)\sin(t/2)]-t+1\\
y(t)=e^{-t/2}[(x(0)-1)\sin(t/2)+(y(0)-2)\cos(t/2)]+2
$$

Answer (score 0):

$${\cal L}^{-1} \left[ -\frac{s+1}{s^2}+(s+1)(x(0)-y(0))+1+s(x(0)+y(0)) \right] = x(0)\delta(t) - y(0)\delta(t) + \delta(t) + 2x(0)\delta^{'}(t) - t - 1 $$

$${\cal L}^{-1} \left [ \frac1 s-s(x(0)-y(0))+\frac{s+1}{s}+(s+1)(x(0)+y(0)) \right] = x(0)\delta(t) + y(0)\delta(t) + \delta(t) + 2y(0)\delta^{'}(t) +1 $$

so:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}X\\Y\end{array}\right)= e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\sin(\frac{t}{2}) \left(\begin{array}{cc}x(0)\delta(t) - y(0)\delta(t) + \delta(t) + 2x(0)\delta^{'}(t) - t - 1\\x(0)\delta(t) + y(0)\delta(t) + \delta(t) + 2y(0)\delta^{'}(t) +1\end{array}\right)$$

finally:

$$X(t) = e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\sin(\frac{t}{2}) \left( x(0)\delta(t) - y(0)\delta(t) + \delta(t) + 2x(0)\delta^{'}(t) - t - 1 \right)$$

$$Y(t) = e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\sin(\frac{t}{2})  \left( x(0)\delta(t) + y(0)\delta(t) + \delta(t) + 2y(0)\delta^{'}(t) \right)$$

and if I have a $y(0)$ and $x(0)$ i put to $Y(t)$ and $X(t)$ ? Or be considered as permanent for example $x(0) = A$ and $y(0)=B$.

$$X(t) = e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\sin(\frac{t}{2}) \left( A\delta(t) - B\delta(t) + \delta(t) + 2A\delta^{'}(t) - t - 1 \right)$$

$$Y(t) = e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\sin(\frac{t}{2})  \left( A\delta(t) + B\delta(t) + \delta(t) + 2B\delta^{'}(t) \right)$$

Comment: This is wrong. The inverse transform of a product is the convolution of inverse transforms, ${\cal L}^{-1}\{{\cal L}\{f\}{\cal L}\{g\}\}=f*g$.

Comment: so $X(t) = e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\sin(\frac{t}{2}) * \left( A\delta(t) - B\delta(t) + \delta(t) + 2A\delta^{'}(t) - t - 1 \right)$ and $Y(t) = e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\sin(\frac{t}{2}) * \left( A\delta(t) + B\delta(t) + \delta(t) + 2B\delta^{'}(t) \right)$  ? But, I used Wolphram alpha to calc this and I have this same answer.